# PHP Curl Work in somecase and not in somecases

Tags: php

**This Code is Working Well**

```
  <?php 
            // create curl resource 
            $ch = curl_init(); 

            // set url 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipdev.in/"); 

            //return the transfer as a string 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

            // $output contains the output string 
            $output = curl_exec($ch); 
            echo $output;
            // close curl resource to free up system resources 
            curl_close($ch);      
    ?>
```

**But below two bunch of codes are not working.** I am not getting an error but in these cases browser loading bar is just revolving and revolving and never stops. The page shows loading and loading for a long time but nothing loads from URL. Where is the problem ?

```
 <?php 
            // create curl resource 
            $ch = curl_init(); 

            // set url 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://iiitd.ac.in/"); 

            //return the transfer as a string 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

            // $output contains the output string 
            $output = curl_exec($ch); 
            echo $output;
            // close curl resource to free up system resources 
            curl_close($ch);      
    ?>

    <?php 
            // create curl resource 
            $ch = curl_init(); 

            // set url 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://iiitd.ac.in"); 

            //return the transfer as a string 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

            // $output contains the output string 
            $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    echo $output;
            // close curl resource to free up system resources 
            curl_close($ch);      
    ?>
```

Comment: My question is; Why are you running the curl twice in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

the link `https://iiitd.ac.in/` is redirecting to `https://www.iiitd.ac.in/` so you need to modify your curl code. You need to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as `true`.

Have a look on below solution:

```
<?php
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://iiitd.ac.in/");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// added follow location
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```